# FPGA proper SDC constraint for hsync pulse

Tags: fpga, sdc

I have a design where video data comes in over the altera altlvds_rx lvds receiver.  One of the parallel bits that comes out the other side represents H-Sync which will show up for a few clock cycles every horizontal video line.  One always block in the design uses h-sync to count them so something like always @(posedge hsync)...

Now Quartus tells me it has decided hsync is a clock which I kind of get and then it tells me it is unconstrained.  What kind of constraint would I put here?  Do I declare it a clock and make it have a very unbalanced duty cycle?  Hsync period is quite large compared to the video clock but the positive portion of the pulse is only a few video clocks wide.

Comment: You shouldn't use HSync as a clock. You should use the pixel/video clock, and then HSync as an enable signal.

Comment: Don't route these signals to the clock inputs of flip-flops. Recommend you look up 'synchronous logic design' on the Internet, should lead you to some well-written guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronize and edge detect the `hsync` input with something like this:

```
reg hsync_reg = 0;
reg hsync_delay_reg = 0;
wire hsync_posedge = hsync_reg & ~hsync_delay_reg;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    hsync_reg <= hsync;
    hsync_delay_reg <= hsync_reg;
end
```

Then count the pulses of `hsync_posedge` with something like this:

```
reg [7:0] count_reg = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        count_reg <= 0;
    end else if (hsync_posedge) begin
        count_reg <= count_reg + 1;
    end
end
```

In this case, everything is timed by clock and you don't need any special timing constraints.  This is also known as using `hsync_posedge` as a *clock enable*, since it's roughly equivalent to routing the signal to the 'enable' input on a flip flop.